# Display form results on same page with action to a different page

Tags: php, html, web

I Have a form with the following in `index.php`:

```
action="calculate.php"
```

In `calculate.php` I do some math with data retrieved from `index.php`.

How can I display the results in some inputs in `index.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you can use session set the value of the result in `calculate.php` then redirect to `index.php` from here, This is where you read the data, you could run some kind of check to see if the result is set in the session and then display it. Don't forget to unset the session result after displaying it.

This would work but It's not the best way to go forward. I would recommend that you do everything in a single file and use a post request to process and display the result, You can also move the calculation logic to functions which can be in a different file and invoke them as needed.

Comment: Okey thanks ! I'll just put functions un calculate.php and call it in index.php

Comment: The problem is, when i submit, the page reload and goes to the main list item (i have collapsible lists), so i have to click again on the list item where i was to see result

Comment: You can also apply an active class to the collapsible item using the same logic. For example, Introduce a variable a boolean variable where you are doing the result e.g `$hasResults = true`
Then in the `div` for the collapsible add the class conditionally
`<div class="some-class <?php $result ? 'active' : '' ?>">
    <!-- html content here -->
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ajax?  Use javascript/jquery to catch the submit event, use ajax to send the data to calculations.php, echo the results back.

Comment: it's just a school assignment we have to use PHP, i guess i'l just put some functions in calculate.php and call it in index.php instead of putting it in action attribute